# `Inject` proc argument into template body

Tags: templates, scope, arguments, nim-lang

Given the following snippet:

```
template myProc(body: untyped) =
  template doStuff(stuffBody: untyped) = 
    proc doStuffArg(a: int) = stuffBody

  body

myProc:
  doStuff:
    echo a

doStuffArg(123)
```

The code will work as long as `a` is not used inside doStuff body. Is there a way to make `doStuff` body aware of this argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular example, both templates has to be marked as dirty in order to prevent the re-writing of the AST aiming to make the templates [hygienic](http://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#templates-hygiene-in-templates):

```
template myProc(body: untyped) {.dirty.} =
  template doStuff(stuffBody: untyped) {.dirty.} =
    proc doStuffArg(a: int) = stuffBody

  body

myProc:
  doStuff:
    echo a

doStuffArg(123)
```